# Bluetooth low energy device gets disconnected if I lock the screen in Moto G

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, motorola

I've developed a bluetooth low energy app. I installed and tested with Nexus 4, Nexus 5, Samsung S4 and HTC one it's working well. But I installed in Moto G and connected the Bluetooth low energy device. Then I clicked the power button, screen gets locked after 2 to 3 minutes BLE device gets disconnected. Any info / help regarding this would be helpful.

Comment: Possible your app is closing by OS, so Gatt closing too. If you need keep Gatt active, you should use a Service bringing to foreground.

Comment: Thnaks! Actually to save the battery life in BLE device,I have increased the time of the adjust connection control to 1.1 milliseconds from 300 milliseconds. it's working well in other mobile devices. But especially the Moto G  is not accepting this value. when the mobile is in sleep mode os itself closing the gatt object.